# Test for invalid bit flags

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, flags

I'm reading user-supplied options from a byte using bit flags. I want to check whether the byte contains any invalid/unknown flag values.

The quick test code I've written so far looks like this:

```
public class Test {
  static byte flag1 = 0x01;
  static byte flag2 = 0x02;
  static byte flag3 = 0x04;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte invalidFlags = 0x0F;
    byte goodFlags = (byte) (flag1 | flag2);

    System.out.println(flagsAreOK(invalidFlags));
    System.out.println(flagsAreOK(goodFlags));

    // prints:
    //
    // false
    // true
  }

  private static boolean flagsAreOK(byte value) {
    byte allFlags = (byte) (flag1 | flag2 | flag3);
    byte badFlags = (byte) ~allFlags;

    return ((value & badFlags) == 0);
  }
}
```

This appears to work OK. However, is anyone aware of either:

- A neater way to do this? I'm not a bit manipulation expert by any means.
- An existing library to handle flag manipulation? I've found [`BitField`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/BitField.html) from Apache Commons Lang, yet there's already a bug complaining about how [impossible the JavaDocs are to read](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-731).

Comment: Are your flags represent a set of constants. If so, you can take advantages of Java's `EnumSet` & `Enum` which save you a lot of work to do with bit fields. There is a very good tips in [Effective Java 2nd](http://dhruba.name/2008/12/31/effective-java-item-32-use-enumset-instead-of-bit-fields/).

Comment: It's pretty neat already. Using `int` to hold the flags would remove the casts.

Comment: I see your code correct. 
But if you don't want to calc 0x1, 0x2, 0x4, you can do "flag1 = 1<<0" (1), "flag2 = 1<<1" (2), "flag3 = 1<<2" (4). 
And if your flags don't have gaps, can check all without OR-all, "allFlags = ((flag3<<1) - 1)"

Comment: @Genzer They represent a set of options that are not mutually exclusive. I guess that rules out `EnumSet`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html), however the way you are doing it is the correct way to check to see if only valid flags are set.

Your example modified:

```
public class Test {
  static BitSet flag1 = new BitSet();
  static BitSet flag2 = new BitSet();
  static BitSet flag3 = new BitSet();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    flag1.set(0, true);
    flag2.set(1, true);
    flag3.set(2, true);

    BitSet invalidFlags = new BitSet();
    invalidFlags.set(0, 3, true);
    BitSet goodFlags = new BitSet();
    goodFlags.or(flag1);
    goodFlags.or(flag2);

    System.out.println(flagsAreOK(invalidFlags));
    System.out.println(flagsAreOK(goodFlags));
  }

  private static boolean flagsAreOK(BitSet value) {
    return value.get(0, value.length()).clear(0, 2).cardinality() == 0;
  }
}
```

You can use `BitSet.valueOf(...)` to create  a `BitSet` from an array of `byte`s. See the JavaDoc for more info.

Comment: In my use case, I receive my byte of data from the user and I need to determine which flags are set (and whether invalid flags are set). I can't see from the `BitSet` API how I would do this. Is it possible?

Comment: @DuncanJones Apologies, I linked an old JavaDoc by accident, see my update for the Java7 version, which includes a `valueOf` method that you can use.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I have to use Java 6, so `BitSet` isn't really an option for me then. I appreciate the answer, however.